# How to start transaction in Camel sql consumer and use it further

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, apache-camel, camel-sql

I am using Camel for integrating Spring Boot application with other domains.
I have a simple route configured using SQL Component for polling and updating DB:

```
from("sql:"+selectSQL+"?consumer.delay=20000&onConsume="+updateSQL)
   .log("---select sql done")
   .to("sql:" + insertSQL);
```

and SQLs are like these:

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE PROCESSED is null and ROWNUM <4 for update skip locked";
String updateSQL = "update T1 set PROCESSED='TRUE' where id = :#id";
String insertSQL = "insert into T2 (col_name...) values (col_value...)";
```

And I would like these SQLs to run inside 1 transaction for single polling request. I know that I can make route transacted with `.transacted("propagationPolicy")` but I can't put it before `from`.

Is it possible make every polling try transactional? 

PS. I have an workaround with timer component and separate route for each SQL but I wonder is it possible to solve my problem using only 1 route as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging in the Camel documentation and source codes I came to conclusion that what I asked is not possible to achieve. So let me post my workaround solution. 
The idea is to use one of components with scheduling like **timer** component. Next transaction could be started, inside which all DB operation are done:

```
from("timer:pollingTimer?period=20s")
    .transacted("propagationRequired")
    .to("sql:" + selectSQL)
    .to("sql:" + updateSQL)
    .to("sql:" + insertSQL)
    .log("processing is done");
```

Eventually some processors could be applied between DB operations to correctly process selected rows.